# Getting database value to display it on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I would like to retrieve database value from a table.

let's say i have  **table_message** that looks like this :

```
| ID  |    KEY       |  MESSAGE           | 
| 1   | app.label1   |  Your First Name   |
| 2   | app.label2   |  Your Last Name    |
```

then i would like to get  ***Your First Name***  and ***Your Last Name*** through ***app.label1*** and ***app.label2*** using a jsp ( i use struts 2 framework ) that might look like this.

```
<s:textfield label="app.label1" name="firstName"/>
<s:textfield label="app.label2" name ="lastName"/>
```

those textfields should populate with label ***Your First Name*** and ***Your last Name*** without requiring *.properties file.  Is it possible ? if yes could you show me how to do that or give an example or any references ?

thanks

Comment: Have you tired to do something?